# Elasticsearch has_child query/filter in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, kibana

I cannot seem to get the `has_child` query (or filter) to function in Kibana 4. My code works in elasticsearch directly as a curl script, but not in Kibana 4, yet I understood this was a key feature of the upgrade. Can anybody shed any light?

The curl script as follows works in elasticsearch, returning all of the parents where they have a child object:

```
    curl -XPOST localhost:port/indexname/_search?pretty -d '{
        "query" : {
            "has_child" : {
                "type" : "object",
                    "query" : {
                        "match_all" : {}
                    }
            }
        }
    }'
```

The above runs fine. Then to convert it to the JSON query to submit within Kibana, I've followed the general formatting rules: I've dropped the curl line and added the index name (and sometimes a blank filter [], but it doesn't seem to make much difference); no error is thrown but the whole dataset returns.

```
    {
      "index" : "indexname",            
         "query" : {
            "has_child" : {
                "type" : "object",
                    "query" : {
                        "match_all" : {}
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something? Has anybody else got a `has_child` query to run in Kibana 4?

Many thanks in advance

Toby